# ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I have a problem when trying to build or compile an environment with Docker Compose on an AWS instance. I have followed the steps of the official documentation for the installation of docker-compose and theoretically it installs without errors. The problem occurs when I run the docker-compose build command within my Dockerized environment.

Here's the installation tutorial I followed:

[image]

Error code:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Error image:

[image]

Comment: The reason I voted down is that the main language of this site is English. Please take the time to formulate your question in English and you might get better results

Comment: Meta SO canonical on Non-English Content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Answer (score 2):

Put the current user into docker group. For example:

```
user_name@ubuntu:/tmp/docker$ sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly
Check with the following commands below:

> docker-compose -version *result in* `docker-compose version xx.xx, build yy12`
>
> docker -v *result in* `Docker version xxx.xx, build yy12`

If the above is okay then you either have to set up docker for non super users please read here [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)

Or run docker-composer commands as a root user E.g `sudo  docker-compose up` or `sudo  docker-compose start`

Please note that xx.xx and yy12  are hypothetical